# Alternate ways of opening swf videos from IE

Tags: javascript, html, flash, web, html5-video

We have a website that has audio-video content in the format of `.swf` files.
There are thousands of active users on the website.

The problem that came up is that some of the new browsers these days do not support Flash.

Some users reported that they are trying to run these files on IE 11 on Win 7. So instead of playing that video, it starts to download itself.

We cannot ask all of our users to use Chrome or try other browsers. We also cannot convert `swf` files to HTML5 supported videos.

Is there any way that we can implement so that these files will play in browsers?

**PS** `swf` files are not working in IE 11 on Windows 7. But they are working on IE in Win10.

Here's an example code we are using-

```
<object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=6,0,0,0" width="400" height="300" id="movie" align="center">
   <embed src="http://www.w3schools.com/tags/helloworld.swf" quality="high" width="400" height="300" name="movie" align="center" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" plug inspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" />
   <param name="movie" value="http://www.w3schools.com/tags/helloworld.swf" /> 
</object>
```

Comment: Flash Video actually means FLV files (similar to AVI or MP4 etc). An SWF is just compiled code (eg: like an .EXE or APK file) that can also be run inside browser (via some plugin)... You wouldn't pack each mp3 as an individual Android app, so why compile each video as own Flash app? That's crazy...

Comment: Are you sure the swf's own code is not actually loading external video files (flv or mp4)? If sure video exists only inside swf app, then **add a link to one sample swf video** & we'll check if still possible to convert to mp4...

Comment: These `swf` files are actually created from PowerPoint slides and Audio using ISpring(http://www.ispringsolutions.com/ispring-converter). So when they play they have option to go to any slide, pause/play/next/previous buttons are also there. These files are placed on DropBox and using that link we are plating that video.

Comment: Aah... so that's why you keep calling them "videos" because of things like `"movie"` in the embed code? The new edit makes it better quality Question. I did not downvote before but now I feel okay to cast my own cancelling upvote.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed the `.swf` link is from W3Schools.com... Their [**example**](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_embed) page shows code to embed an SWF and for me it works fine on IE 11 using a Win 7 PC. The code is basic...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body> <embed src="helloworld.swf"> </body>
</html>
```

> *"Some users reported that they are trying to run these files on IE 11 on Win 7. So instead of playing that video, it starts to download
>   itself."*

It auto-downloads because it's an unknown file type to IE, so it's hoping maybe you know some program to run this filetype *X* if it just d/loads for you.

Internet Explorer uses Windows' own ActiveX for running web plugins. It's a Microsoft technology so likely your end-users assume that just having the Flash plugin installed in their Chromes or Firefoxes is enough. Nope. On PC there are two versions of the same plugin (one for IE only, and another version for all other browsers).

**How to fix this?**...
Using the IE browser itself, go to : **https://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/** 
That page will auto-detect browser & check Flash existence (offers link to correct version for IE). 
Alternatively just choose "IE (Active-X)" from the drop-down list here : **https://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/otherversions/**

**Final note**...
If these are just slides why not just export as images and just display pictures with audio in a web page (this way it would display on mobile browsers too)?

```
<img src="slide1.jpg" />
<audio controls src="track1.mp3" />
```

Just a basic example for a *slide1.html*. The next/back buttons would just be links to other pages like *slideX.html* etc.

Or even try web-searching a "powerpoint to html online converter" tool. One example is this [**conversion site**](http://www.zamzar.com/convert/ppt-to-html5/). I've not tested but it may help you.

> *"These swf files are actually created from PowerPoint slides and Audio using ISpring(ispringsolutions.com/ispring-converter)."*

I guess this supports advanced effects like transitions etc? So why not export as HTML5 option? Unless you feel SWF gives better content protection...

Good luck whichever way you go..